# get the selected nodes in a treeview and drag it

Tags: javascript, c#, treeview

i want to get the selected node and drag it  but the problem is i can t reach the nodes in my treeview ,the treeview is bidding from a database , i want that the selected treenode drag and drop any help plz

PS: i try this for just show me if he cans alert me the selected node or that if it works that mean i can reach the treenode but in my aspx the ".selectedNode.value" don't have such an attibut

```
       <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" 
         OnSelectedNodeChanged =" MyTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged" 
         ontreenodecheckchanged="TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged">

   <SelectedNodeStyle ForeColor="Black" />
    </asp:TreeView>
```

```
 function GetSelectedNode() {
var treeViewData = window["<%=TreeView1.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];
if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "") {
    var selectedNode = document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);
   treeViewData.se

    var value = selectedNode.href.substring(selectedNode.href.indexOf(",") + 3, selectedNode.href.length - 2);
    var text = selectedNode.innerHTML;
    alert("Text: " + text + "\r\n" + "Value: " + value);
} else {
    alert("No node selected.")
}
return false;
```

`

Comment: What does treeViewData.se do?

Comment: as i indrestand it  keep the selected node